# Удалить разрывы строк в выделенном тексте в textarea

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить разрывы строк в выделенном тексте в textarea по событию onclick?

Comment: Всё, разобрался, вроде бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что вы подразумеваете под выражением "разрывы строк"? Да это даже не суть важно. Допустим, вы желаете удалить из текстового поля все пробелы. Тогда поступать следует примерно **по такой схеме**:

```
text = $("#text").val();
while(text.indexOf(' ')!=-1) text = text.replace(' ','');
alert(text);
```

**Ну и полностью( так, на всякий случай ):**

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="text">123123123123 123125435647 3254235213 4534265876978665 464324213213534 0 --=+</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="click_n()">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">

function click_n()
{
    text = $("#text").val();
    while(text.indexOf(' ')!=-1) text = text.replace(' ','');
    alert(text);
    }
```

Comment: >Допустим, вы желаете удалить из текстового поля все пробелы

text = $("#text").val().replace(/\s+/,'');